# Weird appearance about button selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibutton

I'm sure I set right images for different states. But the UIButtons looks not good. Like this:

[image]

[image]

Anyone knows why? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you expect? Post some code of your creation

Comment: @JonasSchafft without that little blue rectangle.

Comment: @EICaptain thx,I didn't do this but fixed it by setting tint color.

Comment: whats  your UIButton type

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change  from `system` to  `Custom` then try ,

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't enter any words(including while space) in all states.I made tint color white.It worked.And I think maybe this is caused by auto layout.